# Template parameter cannot be determined

Tags: c++, templates, parameters, template-argument-deduction

I have a function template that assigns the parameter type `T` based on an `enum` flag provided on input:

EDIT (now includes how to determine the flag)

```
enum class My_enum { a, b};

My_enum someFunctionProvidingTheFlag(double number) {
    My_enum output;
    if (number > 5)
        output = My_enum::a;
    else
        output = My_enum::b;
    
    return output;
}

template <typename T>
T inputFromUser(const double& a_param, std::string& another_param, const My_enum& my_flag)
{
    // do something else
    std::cout << "Please write something: \n";
    getline(std::cin, another_param);

    T result;
    switch (my_flag) {
        case My_enum::a :
            result(150);      // in this case result should be an int
            break;
        case My_enum::b :
            std::vector<int> aux_vector = {1,2,3,4,5};
            result(aux_vector);  // here instead I want a vector
            break;
        // etc.
    }
    
    return result;
}

...

int main() {
    double my_double{23.65};
    std::string my_str{"Great"};
    My_enum my_flag = someFunctionProvidingTheFlag(my_double);
    auto my_value = inputFromUser(my_double, my_str, my_flag);  // ?? cannot determine T
}
```

Is it possible for the compiler to determine the template parameter given the circumstances?

Link to [MWE](https://onlinegdb.com/Ymc0GdCut)

Comment: what do you want `T` to be? It cannot be deduced from the parameters, because there is no relation between `T` and the parameters

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number T should be an `int` if `my_flag = a` or a `vector<int>` if `my_flag = b`.

Comment: is `my_flag` known at compile time? If not, this is not possible (at least not easily, and not in the way you are trying now). A function has one return type.

Comment: Can `std::variant` would be better fit here?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number no, `my_flag` is determined at runtime... I have included how to determine it in an edit to the question

Comment: @Joger The template parameters must be known at compile time. [example](https://godbolt.org/z/xq8vnPf1b)

Comment: @TedLyngmo I see your example works, but I don't understand what `inputFromUser<my_flag>` has become. It lacks the `T` template parameter, so is it still a template? Now instead has a known type value in brackets, so could it be called a "switch" function? (switches according to `my_flag` inside its <brackets>).

Comment: As long as it's a constant expression. So, you will not be able to take user input and from that determine what `T` should be, unless you use `std::any` or `std::variant`